# How can i put "you are entering a number" right below the input box when i select input box?

Tags: javascript, html

CSS:

```css
.Input { background-color:grey; }
.Input:focus { background-color: white; }
```

HTML:

```html
Enter the first number:<br>
<br>
Enter the second number:<br>
<br>
Enter the third number:<br>
<br>
Enter the fourth number:<br>
<br>
Enter the fifth number:<br>
<br>
<br>
Submit
<h1></h1>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function get_product_of_inputs() {
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
        var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
        var f = a*b*c*d*e;
        console.log(f);
        document.getElementById("Submit").innerHTML= ("Product of all the numbers are "+f);
}
```

I am literally trying to put "you are entering a number" when someone select the input field. What can I do?
Please help me out. I am a bit confused at this point?

Comment: Can you supply the HTML code also?

Comment: Pls give us your HTML code of the inputs and also pls specify where you want to show you are entering a number.

Comment: HTML has no `<input>` nor does it have any `#id`'s or any attributes whatsoever.

Comment: Exactly.. And tell us where to write "you are entering a number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onfocus="yourjsfunc();" in your html code.
For example:

```
<input id="a" type="text" onfocus="yourjsfunc();">
```

And use display:none and display:block to hide and show your text-element.

Comment: JavaScript belongs in a JavaScript file. Also, never use 'on' anything (`onfocus`, `onblur`, etc.). It only allows one listener per event, and can be overwritten. Consider `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you. I will consider that in my own projects now.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="number">
      <input id="number" name="number">
      <span data-id="helper-text">You are entering a number</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="foo">
      <input id="foo" name="foo">
      <span data-id="helper-text">You are entering foo</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

## CSS Approach

```css
[data-id="helper-text"] {
  display: none;
}

label:focus-within [data-id="helper-text"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

## JavaScript Approach

```js
function changeHelperTextDisplay(target, style) {
  const helperTextEl = target
    .closest('label')
    ?.querySelector('[data-id="helper-text"]');
  if (helperTextEl) {
    helperTextEl.style.display = style;
  }
}

function handleFocus(event) {
  changeHelperTextDisplay(event.target, 'inline-block');
}

function handleBlur(event) {
  changeHelperTextDisplay(event.target, 'none');
}

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('focus', handleFocus);
  input.addEventListener('blur', handleBlur);
});
```